# How can I deal with multiple text_fields mapped to a single parameter in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, textfield

For instance, I have a table of text_fields like this:
Entry 1 | Value (with flag=TRUE) | Value(with flag=FALSE)
Entry 2 ...
.
.
.

I need to be able to assign the "Value" whether it is in the left or right hand column (and set the corresponding flag).

Then on that same row if one column has an entry, then the other column should be grayed out (otherwise it would overwrite the other one).

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this with extra, non-DB attributes on the model.  Something like this:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord

  attr_accessor :val1, :val2

  def val1=(value)
    self.real_value = value  # Make sure your real database column is updated
    self.the_flag = true
  end

  def val1
    the_flag ? real_value : nil  # Return real database column when asked
  end

  def val2=(value)
    self.real_value = value  # Make sure your real database column is updated
    self.the_flag = false
  end

  def val2
    the_flag ? nil : real_value  # Return real database column when asked
  end
```

Then in your view, you hook up to val1 and val2 instead of the real column and use your flag to determine what's grayed out.

Comment: attr_accessor :val1, :val2 is unnecessary. Both methods it gives you, you override.

Comment: Actually I think I may not have explained in enough detail. What I needed was it to update dynamically based on the flag and the input from the user. Essentially what I ended up doing was base it off of this example: https://github.com/ryanb/complex-form-examples. The key was to use accepts_nested_attributes_for :entries, :reject_if => lambda { |entry| "regex for making sure column1 and column2 are not both filled"}. Next stop is adding Javascript to make the fields gray out dynamically